# How to clear screen in C without any system function or library?

Tags: c, terminal

Clear Screen in the C programming language without use of the system function or any library?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char name[11]="abhinay";
    // The ANSI character to print the "name value"  in the colorful form.
    printf("%c[36m%s\n\n", (char) 27,name);
    printf("\n Hellow world\n");
    printf("[36m %s \n\n", name);

}
```

Comment: PDF search through ISO 9899:2011 for the word "screen": zero hits. Because the C standard doesn't enforce the compiler to handle screens. In fact, the C standard doesn't even know what a screen is.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard or portable way, it depends on your terminal emulator.

You can do it with ANSI escape sequences, which seems to be what you're using.

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) indicates that ED (erase display) is the right command, with code 2, i.e. `printf("%c2J", 27);`.